# How to resize pictures in questions and answers?

Tags: discussion, support

I have answered a question recently and I've put two pictures in my answer. But the problem is that one of them is small and the another one is so big.

I want to resize the big one in my answer to become as small as the first picture, but I don't want the quality to decline.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253403/how-to-reduce-image-size-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `s` and `m` for small and medium image size respectively before "." in your image URL.

For example, if the image URL is like `https://i.stack.imgur.com/6touk.jpg` and you want to keep it medium size, add `m` before dot `https://i.stack.imgur.com/6toukm.jpg`.

[This post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/25052/321725) from Main Meta SE explains in more detail.

> Where the original might be something as obscenely large as this:

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7QBb.jpg

> Slip an m or s character at the end of the file name, just before the file extension, like so:

> Medium:

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7QBbm.jpg

> Smaller:

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7QBbs.jpg